# Docker build process does not use cache in MacOS

Tags: docker, docker-build

I build the same docker images in both Ubuntu and MacOS. When building the images in Ubuntu if the images are previously built, layer caches are used and only the layers which changed are built. However, when I build the same images in MacOS, it does not use the cached layers created by previous builds in MacOS. What could be the reason?

I installed docker via terminal in Ubuntu and via Docker Desktop in MacOS.

Comment: What makes you think that? How did you verify? I think this question needs some more information.

Comment: I do not see the "CACHED" text before the image build step and I can see that process for that step is running. I see apt-get install outputs in the terminal. When I build in Ubuntu, I see the CACHED text and I don't see apt-get install outputs.

Comment: dockerfile for reproduction?